# New Data is Replacing Older Data Instead Adding New Data in C

Tags: c

I am making simple C program. This program should be able to store data in memory (not using database). But when i tested it, it can not store more than 1 data. Every time i store new data, the old one get replaced. I hope these screenshot could help you understand what i mean.

[image: First Data Input]

As you can see, i input first set of data. It shows up with no problem.

[image: Second Data Input]

Then, i added second set of data. Where is the first data ? The No 2 Data supposed to be after the No 1 data. But the first data get lost at all.

This is my input code :

```
//this is function for the input
void masukan() {
    n=n+1; //use n as index for the struct (mhsw)
    printf("\n");
    printf("Masukkan NIM : "); scanf("%s", mhsw[n].nim);
    printf("Masukkan Nama : "); scanf("%s", mhsw[n].nama);
    printf("Masukkan Golongan UKT : "); scanf("%d", &mhsw[n].golUKT);
    mhsw[n].nominalUKT = nominal(mhsw[n].golUKT)*100000;
    printf("");
}

//the nominal UKT = factorial of golUKT
int nominal(int n) {
    int hasil = 0;
    if (n == 1) return 15;
    else {
        hasil = ((n*n) + nominal(n-1));
        return hasil;
    }
}
```

This is my output code :

```
//this is for the output
    void tampil() {
    if (!kbhit()) {
    printf("\n");
    printf(" ===========================================================================\n");
    printf("                                 DATA MAHASISWA                              \n");
    printf("|====|================|====================|==============|=================|\n");
    printf("| No |       NIM      |        Nama        | Golongan UKT |   Nominal UKT   |\n");
    printf("|====|================|====================|==============|=================|\n");
        for(i=0; i<n; i++); //to display record
        {
            printf("%5d", i);
            printf("%17s", mhsw[i].nim);
            printf("%20s", mhsw[i].nama);
            printf("%15d", mhsw[i].golUKT);
            printf("%18d", mhsw[i].nominalUKT);
            printf("\n");
        }
    printf("|====|================|====================|==============|=================|\n");
    printf("\n \nPencet sembarang tombol untuk kembali ke Home");
    getch();
    } else {
        menu();
    }
}
```

This is the whole code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

//global variable
struct mahasiswa
{
    char nim[10];
    char nama[50];
    int golUKT;
    long int nominalUKT;
};
struct mahasiswa mhsw[50];
int i, n, nim;
bool ada = false;
char carinim[10];

//prototype
void login();
void menu();
void gotoxY(int, int);
void loading();
void masukan();
int nominal(int);
void tampil();
void cari();

//main function
void main() {
    login();
}

void login() {
    char user[10], pass[10];
    int x, y;
    printf("Masukkan Username : "); scanf("%s", user);
    printf("Masukkan Password : "); scanf("%s", pass);

    x = strcmp(user, "admin");
    y = strcmp(pass, "admin123");
    if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
        menu();
    }
    else {
        system("cls");
        printf("Gagal Login, Ulangi Proses\n");
        login();
    }
}

void menu()
{
    int pilih;

    system("cls");
    printf(" ____________________________________________________\n");
    printf("|                    Siukat Lite                     |\n");
    printf("|____________________________________________________|\n");
    printf("|_______________________Home_________________________|\n");
    printf("|    1. Pendaftaran Mahasiswa                        |\n");
    printf("|    2. Daftar Golongan UKT                          |\n");
    printf("|    3. Cari NIM                                     |\n");
    printf("|    4. Cetak Data Siukat                            |\n");
    printf("|    Ketik sembarang nomor untuk keluar              |\n");
    printf("|____________________________________________________|\n");
    printf("Masukkan Pilihan Nomor : ");
    scanf("%d",&pilih);

    switch(pilih)
    {
        case 1:
            //loading();
            printf("\nPendaftaran Mahasiswa");
            masukan();
            menu();
            break;
        case 2:
        case 3:
            printf("Cari NIM");
            cari();
            break;
        case 4:
            //loading();
            printf("\nData Siukat");
            tampil();
        default:
            menu();
    }
}

void gotoxy (int x,int y)
{
HANDLE hConsoleOutput;
COORD dwCursorPosition;
dwCursorPosition.X = x;
dwCursorPosition.Y = y;
hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsoleOutput,dwCursorPosition);
}

void loading() {
    int a;
    char x;

    gotoxy(1,12);
    for(a=0;a<=5;a++)
    {
        usleep(500000);
        printf("*",x);
    }
}

//for input record
void masukan() {
    printf("\n");
    printf("Masukkan NIM : "); scanf("%9s", mhsw[n].nim);
    printf("Masukkan Nama : "); scanf("%49s", mhsw[n].nama);
    printf("Masukkan Golongan UKT : "); scanf("%d", &mhsw[n].golUKT);
    mhsw[n].nominalUKT = nominal(mhsw[n].golUKT)*100000;
    printf("");
    n=n+1;
}

int nominal(int n) {
    int hasil = 0;
    if (n == 1) return 15;
    else {
        hasil = ((n*n) + nominal(n-1));
        return hasil;
    }
}


//for find NIM
void cari() {
    printf("\nMasukkan NIM :"); scanf("%s", carinim);
    printf("\n");
    if (!kbhit()) {
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if (strcmp(carinim, mhsw[i].nim) == 1) {
            ada = true;
        } else {
            ada = false;
        }
    }
        if(ada) {
            printf("NIM              : %s \n", mhsw[i].nim);

        } else {
            printf("Data Tidak Ditemukan");
        }
    } else {
        menu();
    }
}

//for showing the record
void tampil() {
    if (!kbhit()) {
    printf("\n");
    printf(" ===========================================================================\n");
    printf("                                 DATA MAHASISWA                              \n");
    printf("|====|================|====================|==============|=================|\n");
    printf("| No |       NIM      |        Nama        | Golongan UKT |   Nominal UKT   |\n");
    printf("|====|================|====================|==============|=================|\n");
        for(i=0; i<n; i++);
        {
            printf("%5d", i);
            printf("%17s", mhsw[i].nim);
            printf("%20s", mhsw[i].nama);
            printf("%15d", mhsw[i].golUKT);
            printf("%18d", mhsw[i].nominalUKT);
            printf("\n");
        }
    printf("|====|================|====================|==============|=================|\n");
    printf("\n \nPencet sembarang tombol untuk kembali ke Home");
    getch();
    } else {
        menu();
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help

UPDATE : i tried to put increment after the insertion and see the value of n. Still doesn't work. Here is some screenshot.

[image: N before insertion]

The value of n before insertion is still 0

[image: After insertion]
The value of n after insertion, it incremented to 1. But the data doesn't get recorded at all.

Comment: Tip: With `char nim[10];
    char nama[50];`, use `scanf("%9s", mhsw[n].nim); scanf("%49s", mhsw[n].nama);` to prevent buffer overflow.  Might be the problem 0 unsure.

Comment: I tried ur tip, doesnt work. Still same issue

Comment: Please comment your code, to explain what you think is done where. That makes looking for potential errors easier. Consider translating everything to English, that also makes searching easier. Please excuse the lack of language skills. Try to make a [mre], which only demonstrates the problem, taking shortcuts everywhere (e.g. hardcode data instead of input). That way you might find the problem already.

Comment: I know it is a bit harder to understand. If this program is for myself, i would have used english for identifier name. And i wil try to put comment on it.

Comment: Please don't post links to code. Please post the whole code itself in the question. 184 lines are not that long. Please don't post screenshots of text. Post the text itself in the question inside code blocks. Please indent your code properly - it will help you and others read your code.

Comment: Thanks for doing that, i was adding the code to the post tho XD. And for the indentation stuff, i swear i did that properly on the Dev C before move the code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `;` after your `for` inside `tampil()`.

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++);
```

It's causing your loop body to be empty so nothing is printed inside `tampil()`.

To protect against such mistakes use a good compiler [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and enable all warnings (for gcc it's `-Wall -Wextra`). Ex. `gcc` outputs this helpful warning message:

```
1.c: In function ‘tampil’:
1.c:167:9: warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
  167 |         for(i=0; i<n; i++);
      |         ^~~
1.c:168:9: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘for’
  168 |         {
      |         ^
```

Comment: Thanks for doing that and for letting me know about the warning. Such a silly mistake by me, it works. And sorry for the indentation, i wrote about that in the comment of question.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the fact that you do the `n = n+1` instruction before the insertion in `masukan()`. You must move this instruction at the end of the function.

When the program starts, the value of n is 0. When you insert a new set of values, you first increment n and store thus the values at index 1. The values at index 0 are the default values.

When you print the values, you print the values with index 0 to n-1. This doesn't include the value at index n that you just inserted.

By moving the increment of n at the end of the new value insertion, the first value set will be inserted at index position 0 and n is the number of values in the table. n is also the index of the after last values in the table. This is where you insert the next value after what you increment n.

EDIT: another error is a ; after the `for(i=0; i<n; i++)` in the `tampil` function. That is the reason one line is printed regardless of the value of n.

Comment: It makes the data doesnt get stored at all. All the record is empty.

Comment: @abw1904 that doesn't make sense. As a global variable, n must be initialized to 0. You insert the first value at index position 0 and then increment the global variable n. Did you increment the variable n after the insertion ? When you print, you print the values at index 0 to n-1. If you incremented the global variable n, you must see all the inserted values. Make sure you don't overwrite the global variable n with 0 somewhere in your code.

Comment: You can see all the variable including n in the pastebin i put on the post, and yes i do not overwrite it with 0 in my code. The global variable is "int i, n, nim;" without any assigned value.

Comment: I suggest you put a print statement to ensure that the value of n is 0 when you insert the input data, and that it is 1 after the value n is incremented in the input function. You then should put a print statement in the output function and verify that n is still 1. It should be, and you should see at least n data lines.

Comment: I have done that, and the index is true. I will update the post with Screenshot

Comment: I have posted the screenshot

Comment: @abw1904 Found the bug. I had to compile and debug your code to find it. See my EDIT in my answer. You have a ; after the `for(i=0; i<n; i++)` in the `tampil` function. Because of this, one line is printed regardless of the value of n.

Comment: Yes kamilcuk have answered that. Thanks for your help tho.